# How to write text to my android IME

Tags: android, ime

I want to send scanned text/barcode to arbitrary application using android input method service.

With

```
activity.dispatchKeyEvent(sendKeyEvent);
```

I can simulate KeyEvent direct to my activity. But I'm wondering how can I send the events to MyIME (already activated), to serve arbitrary connected activities.
I can't find any answer in internet. Can you give some hints?

Comment: ru able communicate to ur own service ?

Comment: IME service is so good capsulated, I have not found how I can do it.

Comment: what do u mean by scanned bar code, what data u want to send ?

Comment: I get barcode from scanner, and can write the barcode (number) to my android activity.But what I really want is to create a IME to provide a service, that user can using scanner to input barcode.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question is pretty simple: use mechanism of broadcast. I was new in android development and thought that I can directly write input to my own IME.

In this case, I can use `LocalBroacastManager` like

`LocalBroadcastManger lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)`

In my Activity reading scanner input:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("...");
//put scanned input data to intent
lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In my IME:

```
public void onCreate() {
    lbm.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("..."))
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //get input from intent and send this to inputConnection
    }
}
```